# Run multiple robocopy command in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, robocopy

I am trying to run multiple robocopy commands in a batch file. But after running the first command batch file exits. Never runs the next command.  
How do i fix that? or how do i run multiple robocopy command in one shot?

for example. diff.bat code is 
`robocopy %1 %2 /E /L /FP /log:%3.log`

Then I want to call diff.bat 3 time with different source and destination directory

```
.\diff.bat \\sorucedir1\ \\distdir1\ mylog1
.\diff.bat \\sorucedir2\ \\distdir2\ mylog2
.\diff.bat \\sorucedir3\ \\distdir3\ mylog3
```

Comment: Can you provide some code?  Otherwise, how can we help you fix?

Comment: Why do you think for loop would work? That is also call the same command multiple times. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling a batch file from inside a batch file, the flow execution is trasferred to the called file and does not return to the caller.

If you want the flow execution return to the caller, you need to use the `call` command.

```
call .\diff.bat \\sorucedir1\ \\distdir1\ mylog1
call .\diff.bat \\sorucedir2\ \\distdir2\ mylog2
call .\diff.bat \\sorucedir3\ \\distdir3\ mylog3
```